# How can I replace multiple empty lines with a single empty line in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a file that contains:

```
something



something else

something else again
```

I need a bash command, sed/grep w.e that will produce the following output

```
something

something else

something else again
```

In other words, I need to replace multiple blank lines with just a single blank line. grep/sed are line based. I've never found a BASH solution that would work on multi-line regex patterns.

Comment: Quick clarification question: Does the file ever have lines that *aren't* separated by a blank line?

Comment: Do you ever have duplicate lines that are not blank? If not, you could use uniq.

Comment: There are lines that are not separated by a blank line.
There could be duplicate lines.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

For BSD-derived systems (including GNU):

You just need `cat` with the `-s` option which causes it to remove repeated empty lines from its output:

```
cat -s
```

From man page: `-s --squeeze-blank: suppress repeated empty output lines.`

Comment: for whatever reason that doesnt work for me `cat -s file1 > file2`

Comment: @qodeninja It didn't work for me either when I was working with files with Windows line endings. Maybe that could be the problem for you too? When I converted the files to Unix line endings `cat -s` worked fine for me.

Comment: in my version of `cat` on Solaris, the `-s` option has a different meaning "-s    cat is silent about non-existent files"

Comment: @VictorZamanian Most of the time it is not possible to redirect back into a file like qodeninja did. For more information, read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/bash-redirect-input-from-file-back-into-same-file

Comment: @FilipAllberg Did they? I see `file1` and `file2`.

Comment: Note that it can be used through a pipe : `some_output|cat -s`.

Comment: All other answers should be deleted, this is the only one you will ever need. (j/k)

Comment: I would like to use it in my mailcap file on the output of links2 but it does not seem to change anything. `text/html; links2 -g -dump %s | cat -s ; nametemplate=%s.html; copiousoutput`

Comment: GNU systems aren't BSD-derived.

Comment: trailing newlines not work.

Answer (score 40):

I just solved this problem by `sed`. Even if this is a 7 year old question, someone may find this helpful, so I am writing my solution by `sed` here:

```
sed 'N;/^\n$/D;P;D;'
```

Comment: This works well for me, and because it's sed, I can use -i for in place fixes.

Comment: Wierdly this also removes the last 2 lines fo the file for me (on OSX sed)

Comment: `sed '$!N;/^\n$/{$q;D;};P;D;'` prevents the last line from being deleted on OSX sed. Also works on gnu sed.

Comment: Thanks, just so you know this is still useful info.

Answer (score 17):

```
grep -A1 . <yourfile> | grep -v "^--$"
```

This grep solution works assuming you want the following:

**Input**

```
line1

line2
line3


line4



line5
```

**Output**

```
line1

line2
line3

line4

line5
```

Comment: I like it, very elegant solution

Comment: Frickin' brilliant, actually. I wouldn't have come up with this in a million years. Nice work. A _slightly_ more robust version goes like this of course (to handle non-empty blank lines): grep -v -A1 '^[[:blank:]]*$' <file> | grep -v '^--$'

Answer (score 13):

Actually, if you replace multiple newlines with a single newline, the output would be:

```
something
something else
something else again
```

You can achieve this by:

```
sed /^$/d FILE
```

Comment: This is correct, obviously :)  What OP likely meant is to replace multiple "blank" (note that this is not necessarily empty, since lines can have invisible white space) with one empty line (which unless it is at the beginning or end of the sequence) means two newline chars.

Answer (score 4):

A solution with `awk`, which replaces several blank lines with a single blank line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{bl=0}/^$/{bl++;if(bl==1)print;else next}/^..*$/{bl=0;print}' myfile
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually, if I find that sed can't do something I need, I turn to awk:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    blank = 0;
}

/^[[:blank:]]*$/ {
     if (!blank) {
          print;
     }
     blank = 1;
     next;
}

{
     print;
     blank = 0;
}' file
```

Answer (score 4):

If someone want use perl

```
perl -00pe0 < file
```

will do the same, as `cat -s` :)

Answer (score 4):

Use awk:

```
awk '{ /^\s*$/?b++:b=0; if (b<=1) print }' file
```

Breakdown:

```
/^\s*$/?b++:b=0
    - ? :       the ternary operator
    - /^\s*$/   matches a blank line
    - b         variable that counts consecutive blank lines (b++).
                however, if the current line is non-blank, b is reset to 0.


if (b<=1) print
    print if the current line is non-blank (b==0)
          or if there is only one blank line (b==1).
```

By adjusting the regex, you can generalize it to other scenarios like squeezing multiple blank lines (">") in email: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59189823/12483961

Comment: I really like this, because it is the first solution that works on DOS files (with \r\n newlines) and because you can change the b<=1  to, say, b<=2   to allow up to 2 blank lines.
Btw you can replace the file inline with:

awk -i inplace

Answer (score 3):

This uses [marco's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/934451/879121) on multiple files:

```
for i in *; do FILE=$(cat -s "$i"); echo "$FILE" > "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Use python:

```
s = file("filename.txt").read()
while "\n\n\n" in s: s = s.replace("\n\n\n", "\n\n")
import sys
sys.stdout.write(s)
```

Comment: this is inefficient while loop

Answer (score 2):

Python, with regular expression:

```
import re
import sys
sys.stdout.write(re.sub('\n{2,}','\n\n', sys.stdin.read()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Super easy to do with vim.  Just open the file and type the following:

```
:%s/\n\n\n*/\r\r/
```

That will reduce all blocks of more than 2 new lines to 2 new lines.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

I take it that you'll probably want to remove lines that only have whitespace.

That can be done with:

```
sed /^[:space:]*$/d FILE
```

Answer (score -6):

Pipelining it to |*uniq* may be solution (if other than empty lines don't duplicate)