# Can I use the sed command to replace multiple empty line with one empty line?

Tags: sed

I know there is a similar question in SO [How can I replace mutliple empty lines with a single empty line in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922449/how-can-i-replace-mutliple-empty-lines-with-a-single-empty-line-in-bash). But my question is can this be implemented by just using the `sed` command?

Thanks

Comment: Try reading all the answers next time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922449/how-can-i-replace-mutliple-empty-lines-with-a-single-empty-line-in-bash/922499#922499

Comment: Actually I have read all the answers. The answer Clue Less and Can Berk Güder provided are just remove all empty lines, not the same as what I needed.

Comment: *-i* switch? *sed -i '/^$/d' text.txt* should work and as far as i've checked it _is_ in answer list (besides *-i* option).

Comment: @barti_ddu: this will delete _all_ empty lines, rather than reduce them into one.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
sed '/^$/N;/^\n$/D' inputfile
```

Explanation:

- `/^$/N` - match an empty line and append it to pattern space.
- `;` - command delimiter, allows multiple commands on one line, can be used instead of separating commands into multiple `-e` clauses for versions of `sed` that support it.
- `/^\n$/D` - if the pattern space contains only a newline in addition to the one at the end of the pattern space, in other words a sequence of more than one newline, then delete the first newline (more generally, the beginning of pattern space up to and including the first included newline)

Comment: +1 Anyway, your example is better, since it will process leading & trailing empty lines correctly, while mine will simply strip them.

Comment: Matching newline at the beginning of the line is not necessary, simply matching newline is enough.

Comment: would someone please explain the sed expression?

Comment: expression: `/.../` match lines via regexp, `^$` regex match empty line (beginning of line followed by end of line) `N` append next line to current line, so now we should have a blank line a newline and another blank line `;` I didn't find anything about this in the manual, maybe this means "branch if line matches" eg "do the next command for double empty lines", `/^\n$/` regex match empty line newline empty line and use D command, which I think deletes the selection even if it contains newlines

Comment: this also appears to work with the original input buffer and not with a post-substituted buffer? I cant seem to combine it like `sed -e s,\ \+,,g -e /^\$/N\;/^\\n\$/D < data`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by removing empty lines first and appending line space with ***G*** command:

```
sed '/^$/d;G' text.txt
```

*Edit2:* the above command will add empty lines between each paragraph, if this is not desired, you could do:

```
sed -n '1{/^$/p};{/./,/^$/p}'
```

Or, if you don't mind that all leading empty lines will be stripped, it may be written as:

```
sed -n '/./,/^$/p'
```

since the first expression just evaluates the first line, and prints it if it is blank.

Here: ***-n*** option suppresses pattern space auto-printing, ***/./,/^$/*** defines the range between at least one character and none character (i.e. empty space between newlines) and ***p*** tells to print this range.

Answer (score 1):

Since *"empty lines"* can contain *"invisible"* whitespaces, tabs, `\f`, `\v`, `\r`, etc.;  in more general contexts we can use

```bash
sed -zE 's/([ \t\f\v\r]*\n){3,}/\n\n/g' inputfile
```