# How to substitute shell variables in complex text files

Tags: linux, shell, string-interpolation

I have several text files in which I have introduced shell variables ($VAR1 or $VAR2 for instance).

I would like to take those files (one by one) and save them in new files where all variables would have been replaced.

To do this, I used the following shell script (found on StackOverflow):

```
while read line
do
    eval echo "$line" >> destination.txt
done < "source.txt"
```

This works very well on very basic files.

But on more complex files, the "eval" command does too much:

- Lines starting with "#" are skipped
- XML files parsing results in tons of errors

Is there a better way to do it? (in shell script... I know this is easily done with Ant for instance)

Kind regards

Answer (score 328, accepted):

Looking, it turns out on my system there is an [`envsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) command which is part of the gettext-base package.

So, this makes it easy:

```
envsubst < "source.txt" > "destination.txt"
```

Note if you want to use the same file for both, you'll have to use something like moreutil's `sponge`, as suggested by Johnny Utahh: `envsubst < "source.txt" | sponge "source.txt"`. (Because the shell redirect will otherwise empty the file before its read.)

Comment: Great! But it only works for environment variables. How can I make it work with the variables that are declared in my .sh script?

Comment: @Ben: use 'export' (before calling envsubst) for every variable you want to use in envsubst

Comment: `envsubst` is part of [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html)

Comment: @user_mda where the output goes.

Comment: Warning: if `source.txt` contains any `$` characters outside of variable expansion, `envsubst` will also replace these and there's no way to escape the `$`. Common (ugly) workaround is `export DOLLAR="$"`.

Comment: Is there  a way to do this without exporting values, like having a file with variables defined? @tlo

Comment: @qodeninja I don't think so, though you could of course just read the file & export the variables in a calling shell. Sourcing it would be easy, if they're in the right format.

Comment: If you want to edit the file in-place: `envsubst < "source.txt" | sponge "source.txt"` using [sponge(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697219/605356).

Comment: @derobert don't worry, sorted it now, it wasn't working because the source and destination were the same file

Comment: @Shardj OK, I just incorporated Johnny Utahh's comment about using sponge. Hopefully that'll save the next person some time.

Comment: If sponge is not available, which is often the case in lightweight environments, you could also use subshell. See this answer https://serverfault.com/a/547331

Comment: you could also use `tee` to replace the file: `envsubst < "source.txt" | tee "source.txt"`

Comment: How do you do this for large files? I see "argument list is too long" when trying to substitute a variable with contents of a large file

Comment: @RenatoVassão no, you can't, that won't work in general. You might get away with it for tiny files (you've basically got a race between reading the file and tee truncating it). You can use `sponge` from moreutils though.

Comment: @Drew putting a huge file in the environment is weird, there are OS-specific limits on command line length and environment size. Some OSes let you up the limit; Linux, for example, with `ulimit -s`

Comment: We use this at work and it's actually really an awful tool. Better off just using other tooling, such as in my case a template engine or script.

Answer (score 100):

In reference to answer 2, when discussing envsubst, you asked:

> How can I make it work with the variables that are declared in my .sh script?

The answer is you simply need to export your variables before calling `envsubst`.

You can also limit the variable strings you want to replace in the input using the `envsubst` `SHELL_FORMAT` argument (avoiding the unintended replacement of a string in the input with a common shell variable value - e.g. `$HOME`).

For instance:

```
export VAR1='somevalue' VAR2='someothervalue'
MYVARS='$VAR1:$VAR2'

envsubst "$MYVARS" <source.txt >destination.txt
```

Will replace all instances of `$VAR1` and `$VAR2` (and only `VAR1` and `VAR2`) in `source.txt` with `'somevalue'` and `'someothervalue'` respectively.

Comment: The single quotes `'` that are used to set `MYVARS` are crucial

Comment: Note that `export`, `envsubst`, or any interleaving command may fail when the text-to-substitute is large. [Reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28865503/2908724)

Comment: @ram that's because omitting the `SHELL_FORMAT` argument (i.e. `"$MYVARS"`) causes all exported variables to be substituted. If that's what you need, then no worries.

Answer (score 35):

I know this topic is old, but I have a simpler working solution without exporting the variables. Can be a oneliner, but I prefer to split using `\` on line end.

```
var1='myVar1'\
var2=2\
var3=${var1}\
envsubst '$var1,$var3' < "source.txt" > "destination.txt"

#         ^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# define which to replace   input            output
```

The variables need to be defined to the same line as `envsubst` is to get considered as environment variables.

The `'$var1,$var3'` is optional to only replace the specified ones. Imagine an input file containing `${VARIABLE_USED_BY_JENKINS}` which should not be replaced.

Comment: you save my life, secret hero, I didn't like the export solutions. Thanks

Comment: Years later, still the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks man, the `'$var1,$var3'` hint is a really timesaver

Answer (score 14):

1. Define your ENV variable

```sh
$ export MY_ENV_VAR=congratulation
```

2. Create template file (**in.txt**) with following content

```sh
$MY_ENV_VAR
```

You can also use all other ENV variables defined by your system like (in linux) $TERM, $SHELL, $HOME...

3. Run this command to raplace all env-variables in your **in.txt** file and to write the result to **out.txt**

```sh
$ envsubst "`printf '${%s} ' $(sh -c "env|cut -d'=' -f1")`" < in.txt > out.txt
```

4. Check the content of out.txt file

```sh
$ cat out.txt
```

and you should see "congratulation".

Answer (score 10):

There is also this option:

#### define your variables in a file

```
$ cat variables.env 
# info about what this var is
export var1=a
# info about var again
export var2=b
```

#### define a template file that uses the variables

```
$ cat file1-template.txt
This is var1: "${var1}"
This is var2: "${var2}"
```

#### generate the final file, with variables replaced with values

```
$ source variables.env
$ envsubst < file1-template.txt > file1.txt
$ cat file1.txt 
This is var1: "a"
This is var2: "b"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want env variables to be replaced in your source files while keeping all of the non env variables as they are, you can use the following command:

```sh
envsubst "$(printf '${%s} ' $(env | sed 's/=.*//'))" < source.txt > destination.txt
```

The syntax for replacing only specific variables is [explained here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294378/replacing-only-specific-variables-with-envsubst). The command above is using a sub-shell to list all defined variables  and then passing it to the `envsubst`

So if there's a defined env variable called `$NAME`, and your `source.txt` file looks like this:

```
Hello $NAME
Your balance is 123 ($USD)
```

The `destination.txt` will be:

```
Hello Arik
Your balance is 123 ($USD)
```

Notice that the `$NAME` is replaced and the `$USD` is left untouched

Answer (score 4):

```
while IFS='=' read -r name value ; do
    # Print line if found variable
    sed -n '/${'"${name}"'}/p' docker-compose.yml
    # Replace variable with value. 
    sed -i 's|${'"${name}"'}|'"${value}"'|' docker-compose.yml
done < <(env)
```

**Note:** Variable name or value **should not contain "|"**, because it is used as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to change your `read` to `read -r` which will make it ignore backslashes.

Also, you should escape quotes and backslashes.
So

```
while read -r line; do
  line="${line//\\/\\\\}"
  line="${line//\"/\\\"}"
  line="${line//\`/\\\`}"
  eval echo "\"$line\""
done > destination.txt < source.txt
```

Still a terrible way to do expansion though.

Comment: Indeed, that's the risk when doing "eval" on a file that could contain bad code

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want to use bash (and sed), then I would go through each of your environment variables (as returned by `set` in posix mode) and build a bunch of `-e 'regex'` for sed from that, terminated by a `-e 's/\$[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*//g'`, then pass all that to sed.

Perl would do a nicer job though, you have access to the environment vars as an array and you can do executable replacements so you only match any environment variable once.

Answer (score 0):

Export all the needed variables and then use a perl onliner

`TEXT=$(echo "$TEXT"|perl -wpne 's#\${?(\w+)}?# $ENV{$1} // $& #ge;')`

This will replace all the ENV variables present in TEXT with actual values.
Quotes are also preserved :)

Answer (score 0):

Call the perl binary, in search and replace per line mode ( the `-pi` ) by running the perl code ( the `-e`) in the single quotes, which iterates over the keys of the special `%ENV` hash containing the exported variable names as keys and the exported variable values as the keys' values and for each iteration simple replace a string containing a `$<<key>>` with its `<<value>>`.

```
 perl -pi -e 'foreach $key(sort keys %ENV){ s/\$$key/$ENV{$key}/g}' file
```

Caveat:
An additional logic handling is required for cases in which two or more vars start with the same string ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is recursive variables substitution:

```
#!/bin/sh
find ./abc -type f | while read file; 
do  
   FF="$file";
   envsubst < ${FF} > ${FF}.replaced
   rm ${FF}
   mv ${FF}.replaced ${FF}
   echo "Replacing ${FF}"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

`envsubst` seems exactly like something I wanted to use, but `-v` option surprised me a bit.

While `envsubst < template.txt` was working fine, the same with option `-v` was not working:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 (Maipo)
$ envsubst -V
envsubst (GNU gettext-runtime) 0.18.2
Copyright (C) 2003-2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Written by Bruno Haible.
```

As I wrote, this was not working:

```
$ envsubst -v < template.txt
envsubst: missing arguments
$ cat template.txt | envsubst -v
envsubst: missing arguments
```

I had to do this to make it work:

```
TEXT=`cat template.txt`; envsubst -v "$TEXT"
```

Maybe it helps someone.