# Setting environment variable to a large value -> "Argument list too long"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

Inside a bash script, I set an environment variable to contain a string of 1 million characters. I do so like this:

```
export LG=XXXXXXX # ... 1 million X's
```

Immediately after this, I am able to echo it back without a problem, i.e.

```
echo $LG
```

However, any other unrelated commands that I attempt to run after this inside the script fail with the "Argument list too long" error. For example:

```
cat randomfile.txt
/bin/cat: Argument list too long
```

I have read through other posts that suggest using xargs to resolve such an issue, but I have not been successful. If I use any command other than echo then I get the "Argument list too long" error even if I don't actually use the $LG variable after I set it. Of course I would like to use the $LG variable, but the error occurs even if I do not use it after it is set.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Edit:**

The overall problem I am trying to solve is something like this:

I have a text file that I need to keep as small as possible (i.e. a few MBs). This text file contains a set of messages that are encapsulated inside a specific network protocol (i.e. header, length of message, the message itself). The message itself can be a string of characters with a length of 1 million or more. So to keep the original file size small, instead of having multiple copies of the large message inside the file, I use a mapping. I.e. if I see the letter A in the message field, I then use sed to find and replace A with 1 million X's. Like this:

```
cat file.txt | sed "s/A/$LG/g"  # Replace A with 1 million X's
```

I will eventually be running this inside a (very slow) simulator, so I need this operation to complete in as few cycles as possible. In other words, a utility like awk that uses a loop with a trip count of 1 million to dynamically generate 1 million X's would be too slow. That is why I thought the environment variable solution would be best.

Comment: What's the purpose of this variable? It's noteworthy that only **environment** variables use up this limited pool of space; if you don't need to export this variable to the environment, and can keep it local to your shell, then this problem becomes quickly moot.

Comment: (...though, on that point -- if you don't need to export this to the environment, you should pick a different name for it; all-uppercase names are reserved by convention for environment variables and shell builtins).

Comment: I added more details in my original question and explained why I believe I will need to use an environment variable. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: The explanation does not make it clear to me why you would need an environment variable for this. `sed "s/A/$LG/g"` does not look in the environment for the value of `LG`; it just substitutes a regular shell variable; you can set `LG=...` without any `export` and still use it in this way. (Mind you, you might get in trouble for that sed command being too large to store on the command line too, but that's a problem you can solve by passing the script to run to sed via a file descriptor).

Comment: I've updated my answer adding a section showing a suggested method for avoiding relying on either the command line _or_ the environment for this value.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now! That partially fixed the problem. Now I get the "Argument list too long" error when piping the file to sed. I.e. `/bin/sed: Argument list too long`. I suppose this is now where I should use xargs? Thank you!

Comment: `xargs` works by splitting a long list of arguments down into many invocations. That works when you have lots of small arguments; it does you no good whatsoever when you have one huge one.

Comment: (BTW, this is the part where I complain about the prevalence of cargo-cult programming in shell -- in this case, copying `export` without knowing what it does and when and where to use it -- and, just as importantly, where and when not to).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! That was a rookie mistake on my part.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Command-line arguments and environment variables both come out of the same pool of space. Set environment variables too long, and you no longer have space for command-line arguments -- and even `xargs`, which breaks command line invocations down into smaller groupings to fit inside the pool where possible, can't operate when that pool is completely full.

So: Don't do that. For instance, you might store your data in a file, and export the path to that file in the environment.

---

By the way -- the reason `echo` works is that it's built into your shell. Thus,

```
echo "$LG"
```

...doesn't need to start an external process, so the limits on argument list length and environment size at process startup time don't apply.

On the other hand, if you ran

```
/bin/echo "$LG"
```

...then you'd see the problem again.

---

Given the explanation edited into the question as to what you're actually trying to accomplish, let me suggest an approach which requires neither environment space nor command-line space:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^-- also consider ksh; faster than bash, but also supports <()
#          /bin/sh is not usable here, as POSIX sh does not specify <().

lg=... ## DO NOT USE export HERE!
sed -f <(printf '%s\n' "s/A/$lg/g")
```

Comment: I see now. I think you meant `sed -f <(printf '%s\n' "s/A/$lg/g") fileOfMessages.txt` ? I think that seems to do the trick. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear this worked! Feel free to mark the answer accepted. (As for `fileOfMessages.txt`, you didn't specify in your question whether you were feeding input via a stream on stdin or a named argument, so I intentionally kept the answer agnostic).

Comment: Is it possible to know how large the limit is?

Comment: @lindhe, `getconf ARG_MAX` shows the total pool size.