# Sed variable too long

Tags: bash, sed

I need to substitute a **unique** string in a json file: {FILES} by a bash variable that contains thousands of paths: ${FILES}

```
sed -i "s|{FILES}|$FILES|" ./myFile.json
```

What would be the most elegant way to achieve that ? The content of ${FILES} is a result of an "aws s3" command. The content would look like :

```
FILES="/file1.ipk, /file2.ipk, /subfolder1/file3.ipk, /subfolder2/file4.ipk, ..."
```

I can't think of a solution where xargs would help me.

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide us with a reduced, representative sample of your input and desired output.

Comment: And you want the whole list wherever {FILES} was found in your json file?

Comment: Question edited, added a sample, and {FILES} is unique, so the whole list replacing that string.

Comment: Would the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865473/setting-environment-variable-to-a-large-value-argument-list-too-long help you here? If you can put your aws command in the same script without the export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way is probably to let Bash itself expand the variable. You can create a Bash script containing a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) with the full contents of `myFile.json`, with the placeholder `{FILES}` replaced by a reference to the variable `$FILES` (not the contents itself). Execution of this script would generate the output you seek.

For example, if `myFile.json` would contain:

```
{foo: 1, bar: "{FILES}"}
```

then the script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat << EOF
{foo: 1, bar: "$FILES"}
EOF
```

You can generate the script with a single sed command:

```
sed -e '1i#!/bin/bash\ncat << EOF' -e 's/\$/\\$/g;s/{FILES}/$FILES/' -e '$aEOF' myFile.json
```

Notice sed is doing two replacements; the first one (`s/\$/\\$/g`) to escape any dollar signs that might occur within the JSON data (replace every `$` by `\$`). The second replaces `{FILES}` by `$FILES`; the literal text `$FILES`, *not* the contents of the variable.

Now we can combine everything into a single Bash one-liner that generates the script and immediately executes it by piping it to Bash:

```
sed -e '1i#!/bin/bash\ncat << EOF' -e 's/\$/\\$/g;s/{FILES}/$FILES/' -e '$aEOF' myFile.json | /bin/bash
```

Or even better, execute the script without spawning a subshell (useful if `$FILES` is set [without export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export)):

```
sed -e '1i#!/bin/bash\ncat << EOF' -e 's/\$/\\$/g;s/{FILES}/$FILES/' -e '$aEOF' myFile.json | source /dev/stdin
```

Output:

```
{foo: 1, bar: "/file1.ipk, /file2.ipk, /subfolder1/file3.ipk, /subfolder2/file4.ipk, ..."}
```

Comment: Very nice trick. Is there another way to call bash as a subshell, so that $FILES doesn't need to be exported as env variable ?

Comment: @Bastien974 Just replace `/bin/bash` by `source /dev/stdin`; see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe perl would have fewer limitations?

```
perl -pi -e "s#{FILES}#${FILES}#" ./myFile.json
```

Comment: Tried, same limitation.

Comment: I'm really surprised. Perl and sed both have pretty amazing buffer limitations (or lack thereof)...

Comment: perl: Argument list too long

Answer (score 0):

It's a little gross, but you can do it all within shell...

```
while read l
do
    if ! echo "$l" | grep -q '{DATA}'
    then
        echo "$l"
    else
        echo "$l" | sed 's/{DATA}.*$//'
        echo "$FILES"
        echo "$l" | sed 's/^.*{DATA}//'
    fi
done <./myfile.json >newfile.json
#mv newfile.json myfile.json
```

Obviously I'd leave the final line commented until you were confident it worked...

Comment: Yeah it works, i'll use that if there's no better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just don't do it? Can you just :

```
echo "var f = " > myFile2.json
echo $FILES >> myFile2.json
```

And reference myFile2.json from within your other json file? (You should put the global f variable into a namespace if this works for you.)

Comment: The json file is used to feed another command: "aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id xxx --invalidation-batch "$(< ./myFile.json)"), so I'm not able to reference.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting all those variables in an environment variable, put them in a file. Then read that file in perl:

foo.pl:

```
open X, "$ARGV[0]" or die "couldn't open";
shift;
$foo = <X>;
while (<>) {
   s/world/$foo/;
   print;
}
```

Command to run:

```
aws s3 ... >/tmp/myfile.$$
perl foo.pl /tmp/myfile.$$ <myFile.json >newFile.json
```

Hopefully that will bypass the limitations of the environment variable space and the argument length by pulling all the processing within perl itself.