# envsubst: argument list too long

Tags: environment-variables, gettext, envsubst

I have an exported variable and a template file. But when I use envsubst, I get the error `argument list too long`.

I use `envsubst (GNU gettext-runtime) 0.21.1`

The problem seems to come from the size of this exported variable, it is 131713 characters long. If I reduce it to 1k, it works.

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45583/argument-list-too-long-how-do-i-deal-with-it-without-changing-my-command) maybe it helps

Answer (score 0):

Solution given by "Charles Duffy" with a very interesting explanation.

[Setting environment variable to a large value -> "Argument list too long"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865473/setting-environment-variable-to-a-large-value-argument-list-too-long#answer-28865503)