# copy into another file while changing some parts batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file that will copy the contents of one file (with problem characters) that sends an email into another file (also vbs) so as to then run it and send a customizable email (customized by various batch things, my program needs to use batch) So I want to use this command:

```
type mailersample.vbs>> mailerfinal.vbs
```

BUT I want to edit certain things. Would I need to go through a variable (problem characters), or would I use the set command, in which case, under which format?

Comment: i am not sure what you actually want, but it sounds to me like you want to substitute variables using bash. if so, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155596/how-to-substitute-shell-variables-in-complex-text-files/14157575#14157575

Comment: what are your "problem characters"? Give us some examples. What have you tried? Hint, read HELP SET and HELP CALL, put some effort on understanding the `~:=` syntax for string substitution, try some simple code, and come back to SO if you have a more concrete question.