# Replace string placeholder with value in sh file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sh

I have to say that in Windows environment /Powershell I would have done it immediately, but since I have to execute this shell script inside a docker Linux image, I need your help.

I have a node.js env file where I store my environment variables, so the nodejs app can use them later.I've set some placeholders and I need to replace them substituting from the event args parameter I got from docker `run command`.

The content of the .env file is

```
NodePort={NodePort}
DBServer={DBServer}
DBDatabaseName={DBDatabaseName}
DBUser={DBUser}
DBPassword={DBPassword}
DBEncrypt= {DBEncrypt}
RFIDNodeUrlRoot={RFIDNodeUrlRoot}
RFIDStartMethod={RFIDStartMethod}
RFIDStopMethod={RFIDStopMethod}
RFIDGetTagsMethod={RFIDGetTagsMethod}
```

I don't know which is the best approach to open the file, replace the values from env variables, and then save it.

Anyone can please help me?
Thanks

Comment: How exactly are the values getting into the container?  If you're passing them via `docker run -e` options, they're already set in the process environment and your Node code should see them in `process.env`; you don't specifically need a `.env` file.

Comment: youre right but this app can run on premise or on container and in the original (premise) it loads from .env so I need to abstract thats from container

Answer (score 0):

You can use `envsubst` which ist part of `gettext-base` package

see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14157575/2087704
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294400/193945

`.env.temp`

```
NodePort=${NodePort}   # notice the `$` before `{}`
DBServer=${DBServer}
..
```

Assuming you are setting environment variables with

`docker run -e "NodePort=8080" -e "DBServer=foo"`

Inside that container you will have to use some `entrypoint.sh` script to run:

```
envsubst \$NodePort,$\DBServer,.. < .env.temp > .env
```

then start your app passing `.env` to your nodejs app.

As an alternative you can also use `sed` to edit `.env`, which might be hard to understand.

```
subst_env() {
  eval val="\$$1"                  # expands environment variable to val
  sed -i "s%\$$1%${val}%g" $2      # using % as sed-delimiter to avoid escaping slashes in urls
}

subst_env 'ENV_DOCKER_DOMAIN' .env
```