# define environment variable in traefik2 to be used in the file provider

Tags: environment-variables, traefik

How would one define environment variables for traefik2 so that they could be used within the dynamic file configuration ? e.g:

```
[http.routers]
  [http.routers.the-rtr]
    entrypoints = https
    rule = Host(`rtr.$DOMAINNAME`)
```

where `DOMAINNAME` would have been defined somewhere (in a file, CLI arguments etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traefik's dynamic configuration does accept Go templating:

> Traefik supports using Go templating to automatically generate repetitive portions of configuration files. These sections must be valid [Go templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/), augmented with the [Sprig template functions](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/).

See https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/file/#go-templating

Note that Go Templating only works with **dedicated dynamic configuration** files. Templating **does not work** in the Traefik **main static configuration** file.

For example, if `$DOMAINNAME` is set as an environment variable, you can do

```
rule: Host(`{{ env "DOMAINNAME" | trimAll "\"" }}`)
```

Note: due to "env" quoting, the `trimAll` is needed — it might be better solution, but it's the better I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's directly supported from traefik product. 
I use file provider and in traefik.toml, I have:

```
  [providers.file]
    filename = "/etc/traefik/dynamic.config.toml"
    watch = true
```

And I use separate mechanism like envsubst to generate (or regenerate as needed) the dynamic.config.toml file. Since I've watch = true, it gets loaded with latest info by traefik

Basically, the snipped you shared in the question can be used as a template file. Then use envsubst or similar to generate dynamic.config.toml.

Q&A on envsubst that I found useful: [How to substitute shell variables in complex text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155596/how-to-substitute-shell-variables-in-complex-text-files)

Hope that helps.

Comment: thks - might try this if I'm really desperate (I have it working ok in the docker-compose environment where you can actually define environment variables). I was hoping for a 100% traefik solution.