# Version number is not read from ConfigMap in this Nginx yaml deployment

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, configmap

If I curl to the container: kubectl exec <my-nginx-> -- curl localhost:80

It displays no version number, just:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Welcome to my Nginx page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>This is version  of my site.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd expect to see the literal string ${VERSION} in the output.

Update:

> I can see the environment variable is set using `kubectl describe deployment my-nginx`. Maybe it has something to do with reading
> envoronment variable from HTML.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  index.html: |
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Welcome to my Nginx page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      <p>This is version ${VERSION} of my site.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
  version: "1.0"
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        env:
        - name: VERSION
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: my-configmap
              key: version
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: html
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      volumes:
      - name: html
        configMap:
          name: my-configmap
```

Comment: What should perform the environment-variable substitution in the static HTML file?  I'd expect to see the literal string `${VERSION}` in the output.

Comment: I don't think this might be natively supported in current ConfigMap implementation. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64113850/how-to-get-environment-variable-in-configmap) SO thread.

Comment: By using Javascript we can get env variable into an HTML file **or** Are you looking to get through HTML only?