# Resolve variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file contains a few lines, and in some lines there is a variable like this:

```
The-first-line
The-second-${VARIABLE}-line
The-third-line
```

In a bash scrip, I want to read the lines and resolve the variable wherever exists.

```
VARIABLE=Awesome
LINES=$(echo $(cat file.txt))
for i in $LINES
do :
  echo "$i"
done
```

The output is same as the input file (unresolved variables) but I want something like this:

```
The-first-line
The-second-Awesome-line
The-third-line
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Use `eval` function

Comment: I can't use `eval` because of security concerns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following (with a recent enough version of `bash` that supports namerefs):

```bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  while [[ "$line" =~ (.*)\$\{([^}]+)\}(.*) ]]; do
    declare -n var="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    printf -v line '%s%s%s' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "$var" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < file.txt
```

In the innermost loop we iterate as long as there is a `${VARIABLE}` variable reference, that we replace by the variable's value, thanks to `BASH_REMATCH`, the `var` nameref and the `-v` option of `printf`.

Warning: if you have a variable named, e.g., `VARIABLE` and which value is literally `${VARIABLE}`, this script will enter an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you `export` your variable you may find `envsubst` does what you want (eg, [How to substitute shell variables in complex text files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70248217/7366100)).

For this particular case:

```
$ export VARIABLE='Awesome'  # or: VARIABLE='Awesome'; export VARIABLE
$ envsubst < file.txt
The-first-line
The-second-Awesome-line
The-third-line
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I'm using a docker container based on `openjdk:11-jre-slim` which doesn't contain `envsubst` by default and I can't add that package (for some reasons).

Comment: @JalalSajadi according to this [Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/635802) there's a docker-related command `envplate`; (NOTE: I have no idea if this is part of a docker default installation nor do I have any experience with this comment ... I'm just passing on what I found with some webs searching)

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do this would be using the sed command to replace ${variable} in the line with $VARIABLE. Make sure to escape the $ in ${VARIABLE} so it doesn't think it's an actual variable. And to use double quotes so it references the variable in $VARIABLE.

```
VARIABLE=Awesome
LINES=$(echo $(cat var_file))
for i in $LINES
do :
  echo $i | sed "s/\${VARIABLE}/$VARIABLE/"
done
```

Let me know if this works for you or if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks jbert! The variables could be anything, not only `VARIABLE`. But I think I can use some regex for catching all other variables.

Comment: This won't work in the case of  `VARIABLE='Awesome&Amazing'`, for instance. Aside from this, there are many problems with this code: Using a `for` loop to read a file is one of them ([DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)).