# Input and output redirection to the same file

Tags: bash

How can I redirect input and output to a same file in general? I mean specifically there is `-o` for the `sort` command and there might be other such options for various command. But how can I generally redirect input and output to same file without clobbering the file?

For example: `sort a.txt > a.txt` destroys the `a.txt` file contents, but I want to store answer in the same file. I know I can use `mv` and `rm` after using a temporary file, but is it possible to do it directly?

Comment: Have you tried using `sort a.txt >> a.txt`. This should append to the txt document rather than overwrite it

Comment: That might also run forever.

Comment: Also, I don't want to append.

Comment: This is BashPitfalls entry #13: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2Ffoo.2Fbar.2F_.3E_file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a file in a command and redirect output to the same file without truncating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6696842/608639)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned on [BashPitfalls entry #13](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2Ffoo.2Fbar.2F_.3E_file), you can use `sponge` from `moreutils` to "soak up" the data before opening the file to write to it.

Example Usage:
`sort a.txt | sponge a.txt`

While the BashPitfalls page mentions that there could be data loss, the man page for sponge says

> It also creates the output file atomically by renaming a temp file into place [...]

This would make it no more dangerous than writing to a temp file and doing a `mv`.

Credit to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for pointing out the BashPitfalls entry in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with the POSIX apis, you'll recognize that [opening a file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) has a few possible modes, but the most common ones are read, write and append. You'll recall that if you open a file for writing, you will truncate it, immediately.

The redirects are directly analogous to those common modes.

```
 > x # open x for writing
 < x # open x for reading
>> x # open x for appending
```

There are no shell redirect that are equivalent to modes like `O_RDWR`, unfortunately.

You can *check* for this with the [`noclobber` option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html#tag_04_127_03), but you cannot open a file for both reading and writing using shell redirect operators. You must use a temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

Not if the command doesn't support doing the `mv` itself after it is finished.

The shell truncates the output file before it even runs the command you told it to run. (Try it with a command that doesn't exist and you'll see it still gets truncated.)

This is why some commands have options to do this for you (to save you from having to use `command input > output && mv output input` or similar yourself).

Answer (score -1):

I realize this is from a billion years ago, but I came here looking for the answer before I realized `tee`. Maybe I'll forget and stumble upon this in another 4 years.

```
$ for task in `cat RPDBFFLDQFZ.tasks | shuf -n 5`; do
echo $task;
grep -v $task RPDBFFLDQFZ.tasks | tee RPDBFFLDQFZ.tasks > /dev/null
done
6551a1fac870
26ab104327af
d6a90cf1720f
9eaa4faea92f
45ebf210a1b6
```

Comment: What do you suppose achieved using the [*tee* command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/tee.html) like this?