# Cat command with redirection results in an empty test file

Tags: linux, centos

```
> #># cat /etc/group > test
> #># cat < test > test
> #># cat test
```

I inputted the second command in prompt 
and checked the test file.
I found that `test_file` was empty.

Why does it happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a file in a command and redirect output to the same file without truncating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6696842/608639), [input and output redirection to the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29899654/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are redirecting `test > test` first but the result of this declaration gives an empty test file. And then you redirect this empty test file with `cat < test` which displays this empty file.

That's why your second and third command print nothing.

Comment: Why the command "test > test " means that declaration gives an empty test file?    ****^^**

Comment: Try to run `which test`

Comment: okayyy thank you !! and i have another question : why "test > test " is faster  executing than "cat < test"?