# Why does `sort file > file` result in an empty file?

Tags: bash

When you try to sort a file in-place with

```
sort afile > afile
```

you silently end up with `afile` being an empty file.

Why is that? I'd expect either an error or the original contents, but sorted.
I haven't tested other shells.

Upvotes for one-liners that do perform the expected behaviour.

PS
[bash redirect input from file back into same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/bash-redirect-input-from-file-back-into-same-file) doesn't address the "why" at all. I know I can go around it with a temporary file. I am interested in what happens. The upvotes for one-liners part was an afterthought in search of shorter ways.

Comment: You could use the output file option `sort afile -o afile`

Comment: my problem was that the output wasn't empty, sort caused empty lines to appear at the top, making it look like the file is empty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `sort afile > afile` this happens:

1. The shell opens and truncates `afile` because of the file direction operation `> afile`
2. The shell executes the `sort` program with one argument, `afile`, and binds stdout of the new process to the file descriptor opened in step 1.
3. The sort program opens the file given as its first argument, which is empty due to the truncation happening in step 1.

You can do it with `sort afile -o afile`