# Is it possible to count the number of times a file is executed?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I usually download lots of images and often clean up with a cleanup.sh file, that only contains a `rm -rf *` command.

My query is, I want to know how many times a do it. Like say, in another file I wanna append the info that file has been executed. 
Is their any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $(($(cat other.file)+1)) > other.file;
```

- `$(cat other.file)` reads the contents of `other.file`
- `$((...+1))` increments it by one.
- `echo ... > other.file` writes the result back to `other.file`

Of course, that requires you to create an initial `other.file` with content `0`.

Comment: its not safe to read from other.file if you redirect the output this same file. see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/bash-redirect-input-from-file-back-into-same-file/6697219#6697219

Comment: In this case, it's OK, because the command substitution is evaluated prior t the input redirection. The problem comes with something like `cat foo.txt > foo.txt`

Comment: @Lynch That sort of problem only occurs when writing begins before reading has ended. This is not the case with `cat`.

Comment: Thanks @Siguza that works perfectly fine. Thanks very much.

Comment: @chepner you are correct. I tested it usin strace and its clearly show that the result of subprocess is evaluated before echo is called: `$ strace echo $(($(cat other.file)+1)) > other.file
execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "6"], [/* 74 vars */]) = 0`. my bad.

Answer (score 1):

In your cleanup.sh, you can do `rm -rf * && date >> cleanup.runs.log`. That way whenever you run it, the date/time is written to the log file, which you can use to count the number of times the script was executed and when.

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
echo "Script was executed" >> logFile
```

Then you can count the lines using the `wc -l`

Comment: Or use [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) for same purpose

Comment: Nice. However he would need to grep the syslog, possible more than one since roundup and the old values will be eventuall deleted.