# Can I output data to the file which is a source of data through redirection?

Tags: shell

I made a script,

```
cat $FILE | sed -e "s/^abc.*$/efg/" > $FILE
```

However, The contents of $FILE results in empty.
If the code is

```
cat $FILE | sed -e "s/^abc.*$/efg/" > another_file.txt
```

the another_file.txt holds the correct results.
If someone knows what is wrong or has solution/suggestion,
please let me know.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The simple answer is that *you can't read from a file and redirect output to it at the same time.* The long answer is too much work to find... (feeling lazy.)

Comment: Thank you Jefre N. Simple answer is enough for me. I just use another_file.txt and copy it to $FILE in the next line.

Comment: I believe you can find the 'long answer' in the comments below [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6696881/6491853), in case you want to learn **why** it doesn't work. :D (Glad the short answer was enough, though. ;))

Comment: Thank you Jefre N again. I make a summary from the post Jefre introduced above.

Comment: Same file cannot be redirect itself. It is because redirection '>' has higher priority than other execution. It means before cat $FILE, $FILE is truncated by a process of '>'. As a result, the $FILE results in empty. Avoid using > $FILE but use | tee $FILE.

Comment: while all of this is true, you're not following good scripting practices. Assuming a modern linux with a modern(ish) `sed`, your problem be reduced to `sed -i '/s/^abc.*$/efg/' "$FILE"`. Notes ; not need for `cat $FILE|`. Use `-i` to write file back to same name. Use sngle-quotes for sed scripts with `$,*` and other shell meta chars unless you're trying to include a shell variable like repl=xyz ; sed s'/abc.*$/'"$repl/"`. And use dbl-quotes around all stnd-usage of variables, i.e. `"$FILE"`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot.  $FILE is created before the pipeline starts

Comment: P.S. if you want to go overboard on fanciness.  I wouldn't, but you can:

txt="$(< $FILE)"
sed -e "s/^abc.*$/efg/" <<<"$txt" > $FILE