# replace and store a value in the same file, shell

Tags: bash, shell

How can I replace the value of a column and store the output into the same file?

example input, file:

```
 #car|year|model
 toyota|1998|corrola
 toyota|2006|yaris
 opel|2001|corsa
```

replace "corrola" with "corrolacoupe"
and store it to the input file

```
#car|year|model
toyota|1998|corrolacoupe
toyota|2006|yaris
opel|2001|corsa
```

I have tried this

```
awk -F '|' -v col=$column -v val=$value '/^[^#]/ FNR==NR  {print $col = val }' OFS='|'  $FILE >> $FILE
```

Comment: What version of `awk` are you using/do you need to support.  Do you need a portable solution, or is `gawk` OK?  If you have `gawk` you could consider it's `gawk -i inplace` or if you have a `sed` that supports it use the `-i` flag (sometimes requiring an argument), or you could use something like `ed` to truly modify the file in place

Comment: no i cant do it with gawk

Comment: also have a look at this answer: ["bash redirect input from file back into same file"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6696881/5092659)

Comment: i want to store the output durectly to the input file

Comment: @Antrebp, can you clarify your question a bit? What are the conditions for replacement? Line/column/value?

Comment: I suggest to copy the file into a temporary file, edit it with awk and then copy it back again.

Comment: Regarding the "replace in the same file" part - that's possible only then deleting characters, not adding, as you are in your example. The only possibility is to create a new, temporary file, and then replace the original with that file.

Comment: i take from terminal an input that told me to change the string of 2nd line and 3rd column

Comment: Are you counting commented lines, when you say 2nd line?

Comment: I fixed the answer on the semaphore question. It was me who mistakenly had the _exit in the parent. I moved it to the child. Now if you remove all the sem_posts and sem_waits, the children will run in parallel. (You'll get the output lines in random order depending on how the OS decides to run the processes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply **replace the value in `(row,col)`** with a new value:

```
$ awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' -v row=2 -v col=3 -v val=corollacoupe 'NR==row {$col=val} 1' file 
#car|year|model
toyota|1998|corollacoupe
toyota|2006|yaris
opel|2001|corsa
```

This will set the value of input field `col` to `val`, but only in the input record `row`. The `1` in the end will ensure each record is printed by default. Input and output field separators are set via `-F` option and `OFS` variable.

If you need to make these **changes in-place**, create a temporary output file and then copy it over the original:

```
$ awk ... file >file.tmp && cp file{.tmp,}
```

Alternatively, in **GNU `awk`**, you can use the **`inplace` library** via `-i inplace` option:

```
$ awk -i inplace -F'|' -v OFS='|' -v row=2 -v col=3 -v val=corollacoupe 'NR==row {$col=val} 1' file
```

If you wish to **skip the comments**, and count only non-comment rows:

```
$ awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' -v row=1 -v col=3 -v val=x '/^[^#]/ {nr++} nr==row {$col=val} 1' file 
#car|year|model
toyota|1998|x
toyota|2006|yaris
opel|2001|corsa
```

Comment: this is very helpfull bua i want to store the output durectly to the input file

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. By writing at the beginning you would overwrite the contents of the original file. You must create a temporary file (see second section in my answer). In GNU `awk` you can use the `inplace` library (see my update).

Answer (score 0):

An `ed` solution that modifies the file in-place without any temporary files could be something like:

```
ed "$FILE" <<< $',s/|corrola$/|corrolacoupe/g\nw'
```

which uses an ANSI-C string to prevent special characters from being treated specially, then matches `|corrola` at the end of any line and replaces it with `|corrolacoupe`.  Then we issue the `w` command to `ed` to have it write the file back out

Answer (score 0):

A really simple solution.

```
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ cat file
#car|year|model
toyota|1998|corrola
toyota|2006|yaris
opel|2001|corsa
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ sed -ri 's@^(.+)\|(.+)\|corrola$@\1|\2|corrolacoupe@' file
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ cat file
#car|year|model
toyota|1998|corrolacoupe
toyota|2006|yaris
opel|2001|corsa
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$
```