# how to replace the first line of a file with the first line of another file

Tags: bash, text, sed, replace

i have 2 txt files : file1 and file2
i would like to replace the first line of file2 with the first line of file1, with a **bash** command

**file1:**

```
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
cccccccc
```

**file2:**

```
zzzzzzzz
yyyyyyyy
wwwwwwww
```

**expected result of file2:**

```
aaaaaaaa
yyyyyyyy
wwwwwwww
```

this can't be done with **sed** as you don't know what to replace with what...i'm right? so how to do this ?

**EDIT:**

so in my particular case (i do it in my openwrt router), what worked is :

```
sed -i "1c $(sed 1q file1)" file2
```

Thanks to @Sundeed for the link explaining why some commands were only displaying the results in the shell but not writing in the file : https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2Ffoo.2Fbar.2F_.3E_file

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: i'm not a bash guru, i have some examples about how to replace a text you know with another text you know in a file. i didn't find any example with a text you don't know coming from a file into another file with a text you don't know too. that's why i'm asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '1R file1' -e '1d' file2
```

Read the first line of file2. Read the first line of file1 and insert it into the output, then delete the first line of file2. Now read and output the rest of file2.

Comment: i tried : sed -e '1R /etc/shadow' -e '1d' /overlay/$(cat /proc/banktable/inactive)/etc/shadow and it says : sed: unsupported command R (i'm doing this on an OpenWRT router)

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `head` and `tail` for this task:

```
head -n 1 Input_file1 && tail -n 2  Input_file2
```

Output will be as follows:

```
aaaaaaaa
yyyyyyyy
wwwwwwww
```

Comment: Minor nit: the `-1` notation is considered obsolete and not specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html); instead, `-n 1` should be used (see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/head-invocation.html), at the very bottom).

Comment: @BenjaminW., thank you sir, added the same now to solution too.

Comment: thank you very much, this is less "technical" than sed, that's why i like it ;)

Comment: (And `-2` as well ;) )

Comment: the output in the shell is correct, but it doesn't write the line inside file2 ? i tried to add >file2 at the end of the command but it doesn't work...it makes an empty file

Comment: @cetipabo see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2Ffoo.2Fbar.2F_.3E_file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/bash-redirect-input-from-file-back-into-same-file

Comment: @sundeep Thank you very much for this link !

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can do this with `sed`, but why would you?

```
sed "1c\\
$(sed 1q file1)
" file2
```

Comment: whouaou, thank you william ! so what's the meaning of 1c and 1q ? i can't even find this in the manual https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Comment: @cetipabo https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-c-_0028change-to-text-lines_0029-command and https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-q-_0028quit_0029-command

Comment: when i do this: sed "1c $(sed 1q /etc/shadow)" /overlay/$(cat /proc/banktable/inactive)/etc/shadow it doesn't change the line and just display the content of the file in the shell...i'm doing this in an OpenWrt router so maybe sed is not compiled with all possible options ?

Comment: this is working : sed "1c $(sed 1q file1)" file2 | tee file3 but i don't want to create a file3 ! if i use | tee file2 i just create an empty file2, so looks like i can't overwrite file2 if it is opened by sed ?!

Comment: well so finaly this is what worked ! sed -i "1c $(sed 1q file1)" file2

Comment: potong's sed solution is really much better than this.  My solution is something I would never consider using, potong's is actually reasonable.

Comment: unfortunately his solution gives me a : unsupported command R

Answer (score 1):

Or with ed

```
f1="file1";f2="file2";printf "%s\n" '2,$d' "r $f2" '2d' "wq $f2" | ed -s "$f1"
```