# Cannot execute script conditionally

Tags: bash

Here's my script:

```sh
if [[ $(jq '.haystack | index("needle")' /etc/xyz/daemon.json) = \0 ]] ; then
    jq '.haystack += ["needle"]' /etc/xyz/daemon.json > daemon.json
    mv -f daemon.json /etc/xyz/daemon.json
fi
```

I want to add `needle` to `haystack` array in a `daemon.json` file. However the problem is in the `if` construct of the shell. When I test the condition with `echo True/False` the terminal does show `True` or `False` based on the command in the condition. However, I cannot do any other command, such as a simple `ls` or `mkdir`. I execute the command from terminal, not saving into a `bash` file. Newline doesn't seem to need `\`.

I'm completely new to Linux terminal, is there something I'm missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], with complete and runnable code? We won't have a copy of `daemon.json`.

Comment: A place it might start is to include the logs from `bash -x yourscript` [edit]ed into the question text.

Comment: BTW, what directory is this run in? If it's run in `/etc/xyz`, the reasons it fails should be fairly obvious.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to use `\0` rather than just `0`. (The shell's behavior on seeing a backslash is not well-specified by POSIX; it may either discard it or treat it as literal, as an implementation decision).

Comment: If you only want to add `"needle"` if it isn't already there, you would need to check if `index` returns `null`, not 0 (which indicates that "needle" is the first element in the list).

Answer (score 2):

Moving your input to a function to allow testing, and replacing `\0` (which has undefined behavior) with `0` (which always expands precisely to itself when given as a literal in code):

```
get_current_json() {
  printf '%s\n' '{"haystack": ["needle", "other1", "other2"]}'
}

if [[ $(jq '.haystack | index("needle")' < <(get_current_json) ) = 0 ]] ; then
  echo "Found (at position 0)"
else
  echo "Not found (at position 0)"
fi
```

...correctly emits `Found`. Thus, the issue cannot be reproduced given only the code provided in the question, without further context.

---

One potential piece of context: If you're running this in `/etc/xyz`, then `> daemon.json` is opening the file for output with the `O_TRUNC` flag, and thus emptying its contents, *before* `jq` begins execution (which can happen only after its output file descriptor is connected), and thus before `jq` is able to read any prior values which the `open(..., O_TRUNC)` would delete.

To avoid this, you should use a unique name for your temporary files, as created by `mktemp`. (Ideally, those names should be *in the same directory* as the destination file, to guarantee that they don't cross filesystem boundaries and that the final `mv` will be atomic). See [How can I use a file in a command and redirect output to the same file without truncating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/how-can-i-use-a-file-in-a-command-and-redirect-output-to-the-same-file-without-t)

Comment: You could use `-e / --exit-status`: `if  jq --exit-status '.haystack | index("needle")' < <(get_current_json) ) >/dev/null  ; then`

Comment: Good call! Always more efficient to avoid an unnecessary command substitution. Though that would differ in behavior from the OP's initial code; to match their semantics, we'd need a `== 0`, even if it's moved into the jq code.