# jq - can't append objects to array in while loop

Tags: json, bash, append, jq

I've got this `service-accounts-list.txt` file with service accounts:

```
serviceAccount:p12345-001@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com
serviceAccount:p12345-002@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com
serviceAccount:p12345-003@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com
serviceAccount:p12345-004@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com
serviceAccount:p12345-005@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

and this `results.json` file which I'd like to append data to:

```
{
  "access": [
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "specialGroup": "projectWriters"
    },
    {
      "role": "OWNER",
      "specialGroup": "projectOwners"
    },
    {
      "role": "READER",
      "specialGroup": "projectReaders"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected result**: I'd like to add an object for each line in `service-accounts-list.txt`, like so:

```
{
  "access": [
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "specialGroup": "projectWriters"
    },
    {
      "role": "OWNER",
      "specialGroup": "projectOwners"
    },
    {
      "role": "READER",
      "specialGroup": "projectReaders"
    },
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "userByEmail": "serviceAccount:p12345-001@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "userByEmail": "serviceAccount:p12345-002@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "userByEmail": "serviceAccount:p12345-003@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "userByEmail": "serviceAccount:p12345-004@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "userByEmail": "serviceAccount:p12345-005@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

My bash script so far looks like this:

```
while read p;
do
  cat result.json | jq --arg email "$p" '.access += [{"role": "WRITER", "userByEmail": $email}]' > result.json
done < service-accounts-list.txt
```

The resulting `result.json` file is actually empty. If I redirect the output to for `example > result2.json` it correctly adds the last service account, like so:

```
{
  "access": [
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "specialGroup": "projectWriters"
    },
    {
      "role": "OWNER",
      "specialGroup": "projectOwners"
    },
    {
      "role": "READER",
      "specialGroup": "projectReaders"
    },
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "userByEmail": "serviceAccount:p12345-005@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

so it seems the `jq` syntax is correct. I've tried adding the `--unbuffered` flag to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: For your convenience, [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2094) and other common problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. That looks useful for a bash scripting newbie like me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the simplest efficient solution would be:

```
jq -nR --argfile result result.json '
  $result 
  | .access += [{role: "WRITER", userByEmail: inputs}] 
' service-accounts-list.txt
```

Notice -- no slurping, no splitting, no shell scripting.  If the use of --argfile bothers you, feel free to use --slurpfile but "unslurp" $result by writing `$result[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

While obvious problem is that you are reading and redirecting to same file which you cannot do in `bash` and [this answer has many useful explanations and work around for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/how-can-i-use-a-file-in-a-command-and-redirect-output-to-the-same-file-without-t).

But a better solution would be to totally avoid invoking `jq` multiple times in a loop and get it done in a single execution of `jq`.

```
# array to hold new values in json format
narr=()

# loop through input file and append json formatted values to array
while read -r line; do
    narr+=('{"role": "WRITER", "userByEmail": "'$line'"}')
done < service-accounts-list.txt

# call jq only once using -n option
jq -n 'input | .access += [inputs]' results.json <(printf '%s\n' "${narr[@]}")
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "access": [
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "specialGroup": "projectWriters"
    },
    {
      "role": "OWNER",
      "specialGroup": "projectOwners"
    },
    {
      "role": "READER",
      "specialGroup": "projectReaders"
    },
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "userByEmail": "serviceAccount:p12345-001@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "userByEmail": "serviceAccount:p12345-002@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "userByEmail": "serviceAccount:p12345-003@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "userByEmail": "serviceAccount:p12345-004@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "userByEmail": "serviceAccount:p12345-005@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jq` itself without any shell processing. Process the plain text file using raw input mode `-R` over null input and start forming the resultant JSON from scratch.

The `reduce()` function iteratively runs over each entry int the text file and creates a object with role name and appends it to the `access` array.

```
jq -Rn \
   --slurpfile res result.json \
   '[ inputs | split("\n") | add ] as $data 
    | $res[] 
    | reduce $data[] as $d (.; .access += [{ role: "WRITER", userByEmail: $d  }] )' \
service-accounts-list.txt
```