# Unable to overwrite exiting file using output redirection >

Tags: bash, perl, unix

A file named start.txt exists.
I am using a perl command which gives modified output using the content of start.txt and i am trying to overwrite the modified output to the same file

```
cat start.txt | perl -ne 'print "$1-$1.mp4 Lecture $2 -\n" while /.*\/videos\/(.*?mp4).*?(?<= )(\d+)/g;'> start.txt
```

Running the above command makes the file start.txt empty for some reason

There's no issue with my command because if i create a new file for redirecting the output like..

```
cat start.txt | perl -ne 'print "$1-$1.mp4 Lecture $2 -\n" while /.*\/videos\/(.*?mp4).*?(?<= )(\d+)/g;'> test.txt
```

This perfectly saves the expected output in test.txt but I don't want to create extra files , i need to overwrite the exiting file itself.

I tried `>|`after reading its used to force overwrite files but still same issue.
I even tried `| tee start.txt` , still causes the file to become empty .

On a side note : There are some awk commands which i use , if i try to save/redirect the output in a file from which the awk function reads text from , it causes the same issue of making the output file empty
I would paste the awk command too if someone asks although i think there would be a universal solution for this

Comment: I recommend not writing to the file you are reading from, it will break the file.

Comment: Take a look at perl's `-i` option.

Comment: @Cyrus thanks i understood the issue now

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I use a file in a command and redirect output to the same file without truncating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/how-can-i-use-a-file-in-a-command-and-redirect-output-to-the-same-file-without-t)

Comment: @oguzismail that's nice , the accepted answer will definitely serve my purpose , thanks for sharing

Comment: @oguz ismail, Those are nice general solutions, but Perl's `-i` option would be better here.

Comment: @ikegami the point is that the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @oguz ismail Maybe, but not of the question you linked. The same question can have different answers for different languages, and that's the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for an empty file in this command

```
cat start.txt | perl -ne 'print "$1-$1.mp4 Lecture $2 -\n" while /.*\/videos\/(.*?mp4).*?(?<= )(\d+)/g;'> start.txt
```

is the

```
> start.txt
```

bit.

When you enter the command into the shell, the shell parses it and prepare things for running. It creates the unnamed pipe to communicate `cat` with `perl` and it also opens the output file, truncating it, and redirected the `perl` standard output to the file. Finally, now that all needed redirections are in place, it starts the different commands. `cat` and `perl` in this case. But the file that `cat` is going to read has already been truncated by the redirection you asked the shell to do.

As already pointed in a comment, your best bet is to avoid writing to the same file you are reading from.

Comment: . I remembered a very small thing i had to ask which remotely relates to the question too , is there any command in linux which can clear all text from a file , not delete file but just delete its text/content ?

Comment: You just used it! The source of all your trouble: `> file_to_clear`

Comment: thanks although for some reason doing it was causing my terminal to get stuck , doing - ```: > file_to_clear``` working instantly

Comment: @Sachin See also the `truncate` utility.

Comment: @ikegami thanks fo suggestion ,  i will check out perl -i and truncate utility