# How to use Sox for all files in a directory

Tags: shell, sox

How do I change the sample rate for every file in the folder?

The following code converts the files, but it erases the file. After this command, every wav file is empty.

```
for i in wav/*.wav; do
    sox -r 8000 -e unsigned -b 16 -c 1 "$i" "$i"
done
```

How do I run the code to every file in the directory?

Comment: I don't know `sox`, but I'm guessing you're trying to write to the same file you're reading, and that truncates the file - see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6696842/3266847).

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
for i in wav/*.wav; do
    sox -r 8000 -e unsigned -b 16 -c 1 "$i" "$i_modified"
done
```