# Whenever I use sed to substitute changes, the redis.conf file is empty inside

Tags: sed, redis

I know this may sound weird but I am not understanding why this is occurring. So here is how it goes. I want to write a bash script to changes these variables on `redis.conf` which is located in `/etc/redis/redis.conf`. The script is like so:

```
sudo sed -e "s/^daemonize no$/daemonize yes/" \
  -e "s/^# unixsocket /var/run/redis-server.sock$/unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock/" \
  -e "s/^# unixsocketperm 700$/unixsocketperm 770/" \
  -e "s/^# maxclients 10000$/maxclients 512/" \
  -e "s/^databases 16$/databases 128/" /etc/redis/redis.conf | sudo tee /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Once ran, I receive an error on sed finding no substitution to change. I look in the `/ect/redis/redis.conf` file and everything is empty inside. No configuration whatsoever. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong. I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Almost-duplicate: [How can I use a file in a command and redirect output to the same file without truncating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6696842/3266847)

Comment: Your command has the form `sed -e "s/A/B/" redis.conf`; is there a file named `redis.conf` in the working directory?

Comment: You also have to either escape all your `/`, or use different delimiters for `s`

Comment: Thank you for the reply guys. @Beta yes, let me correct that I should have changed this but yes the file direction is like so: `/etc/redis/redis.conf`. I'll update that in my original post. (I still receive an error.)

Comment: @BenjaminW. I'll look into that. What would be this approach?

Comment: You can use any other character: `s|/a/b/c|/d/e/f|`, `s#foo#bar#`...

Comment: If you keep forward slashes, you have to escape like `s/\/a\/b\/c/\/d\/e\/f/`

Comment: @BenjaminW. That solved it Benjamin. Also, I did not look into `sed`'s documentation of the difference between `-e` and `-i`. I tested it and it did work with one line but going to test all of them. I'll report back once I get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. The code looks like this now which works perfectly to what I need.

```
if [ ! -d "/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]; then
  sed -i "s|^# unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis-server.sock$|unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock|
          s|^# unixsocketperm 700$|unixsocketperm 770|
          s|^# maxclients 10000$|maxclients 512|
          s|^databases 16$|databases 128|" /etc/redis/redis.conf
fi
```

Benjamin W. was a great help for helping me understanding delimiters and for digging deeper into `sed` commands. I hope this can help others who are configuring `redis.conf` for their environment.