# How to modify a json file by a variable using JQ in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, jq

I would like to modify a json file using JQ in a Bash script. Here is what I tried to proceed:

```sh
var="test-54342"
echo "$( jq '.context["customer-name"] = "$var"' cdk.json )" > cdk.json
```

I also tried this but it's not working as well:

```sh
var="test-54342"
echo `$( jq '.context["customer-name"] = "$var"' cdk.json )` > cdk.json
```

Here is what my json file looks like:

```json
{
  "app": "mySuperApp",
  "context": {
    "customer-name": "text-I-want-to-modify"
  }
}
```

Comment: See `jq --arg`, as described in existing Q&A

Comment: BTW, don't use `echo "$(somecommand)" >file`; just run `somecommand >file`

Comment: Also, redirecting output to the same file you're trying to read from doesn't work. See: [How can I use a file in a command and redirect output to the same file without truncating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/how-can-i-use-a-file-in-a-command-and-redirect-output-to-the-same-file-without-t)

Comment: Ahh, _that's_ why the OP is using the `echo "$(...)"` hack. Not that it's a reliable workaround for the bug (because redirections run before the commands they apply to start, whether the input will still be available to read is undefined), but it explains the intent.

Comment: Yep, I found this hack to avoid using another temp variable. So how can I pass a variable in the `echo` command?

Comment: @SébastienSerre Use `jq --arg`, as Charles said and the linked duplicate explains in more detail.