# How to remove duplicate lines in a file?

Tags: bash, sorting, uniq

I understand that the general approach is to use something like

```
$ sort file1.txt | uniq > file2.txt
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to do this without needing separate source and destination files, even if it means it can't be a one-liner.

Comment: `sort file1.txt | uniq | sponge file1.txt`?

Comment: `echo "$(sort file1.txt | uniq)" >file1.txt`?

Comment: FYI `sort file1.txt | uniq` = `sort -u file1.txt`

Comment: See: [How can I use a file in a command and redirect output to the same file without truncating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6696842/3776858)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the `-o` and `-u` options of `sort`:

```
sort -o file -u file
```

You don't need even to use a pipe for another command, such as `uniq`.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for "inplace" editing:

```
awk -i inplace '!seen[$0]++' file1.txt
```

As with all tools (except `ed` which requires the whole file to be read into memory first) that support "inplace" editing (`sed -i`, `perl -i`, `ruby -i`, etc.) this uses a temp file behind the scenes.

With any awk you can do the following with no temp files used but about twice the memory used instead:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++{a[++n]=$0} END{for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[i] > FILENAME}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

With Perl's `-i`:

```
perl -i -lne 'print unless $seen{$_}++' original.file
```

- `-i` changes the file "in place";
- `-n` reads the input line by line, running the code for each line;
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to `print`;
- The `%seen` hash idiom is described in [perlfaq4](https://perldoc.pl/perlfaq4).

Comment: I don't think `-l` is needed here: you're not manipulating the line, just treating it as an atomic string.

Comment: @glennjackman: If the last line didn't end in a newline, you could get a duplicate...

Comment: @choroba if the last line didn't end in a newline then it wouldn't be a valid POSIX text file and so YMMV with what any tool does with it.

Comment: @EdMorton: The OP doesn't mention POSIX, it doesn't mention "text file" either.

Comment: I know, but the `sort` utility the OP is using in the question is only guaranteed to work on text files so I think it's reasonable to assume the input is text files.

Answer (score 1):

A common idiom is:

```sh
temp=$(mktemp)
some_pipeline < original.file > "$temp" && mv "$temp" original.file
```

The `&&` is important: if the pipeline fails, then the original file won't be overwritten with (perhaps) garbage.

The Linux `moreutils` package contains a program that encapsulates this away:

```sh
some_pipeline < original.file | sponge original.file
```