# Where does the command in the braces run?On current bash or on the newly opening Telnet terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, redirect

Where does the command in the braces run? In current bash or the newly opening Telnet terminal?

```
{
sleep 2
echo "root"
sleep 2
echo "password"
} | telnet 192.168.1.11
```

If the command in the braces is run in current bash, then both the command before the pipe(`|`) and after the command are started at the same time? It's really out of my expectation.

I used to call commands like `find . -type f | du -sh`, I thought `du` is called when `find` has finishes its work.

Could somebody shed somelight on this matter?

Comment: The commands are run in the current bash and their output sent to the pipe.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Do you mean both `{
sleep 2
echo "root"
}` and `telnet` are started **almost**  at the same time other than `telnet` is started after the command in the braces finishes its work?

Comment: Yes, (almost) at the same time

Comment: Try something like `(date>/dev/tty; sleep 5) | (date>/dev/tty; sleep 5)` and you'll see the same date twice but the entire pipeline takes almost 5secs to run

Comment: Better take a look at [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Good example! For `find . -type f | du -sh`, both `find` and `du` are started at the same time, and  the `stdin` of `du` is linked to the `stdout` of `stdout` of `find`, so `du` `waits` for the output of `find`. Am I right?

Comment: Basically yes. Here are some examples: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano The link is very useful indeed. But it's a pity that it does not explicitly tell the readers the command after the pipe and before pipe are **started almost at the same time**. *And what's worse*, many readers like me are more likely thought that the commands called in sequence.

Comment: @John This is a fairly common misunderstanding, but I think it's also rather difficult to explain clearly (parallel processing is inherently a bit tricky to understand) and trying to explain it anytime we explain pipes would just cause more (different) confusion. BTW, there's a related (also common) mistake about redirecting output with `>`, which actually starts (and empties the file) *before* the command runs (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/how-can-i-use-a-file-in-a-command-and-redirect-output-to-the-same-file-without-t)).

Comment: Usually commands in `{ ... }` run in the current bash but this it not true for `{ ... } | ...`. eg. `{ pgrep bash | wc -l; }; ( pgrep bash | wc -l ); { pgrep bash | wc -l; } | cat`

Comment: @jhnc What's `{ ... } | .... eg. { pgrep bash | wc -l; }; ( pgrep bash | wc -l ); { pgrep bash | wc -l; } | cat`?

Comment: `...` are [ellipses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis). The examples illustrate that the number of shells running differs when braces are in a pipeline (in a pipeline, braces are equivalent to using parentheses)

Comment: @jhnc Why they are different in `{ pgrep bash | wc -l; }; ( pgrep bash | wc -l ); { pgrep bash | wc -l; } | cat`?

Comment: Because [each command in a pipeline is executed in a subshell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html)