# Why does reading and writing to the same file in a pipeline produce unreliable results?

Tags: bash, sed, io-redirection, cat

I have a bunch a files that contain many blank lines, and want to remove any repeated blank lines to make reading the files easier. I wrote the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in * ; do cat "$file" | sed 's/^ \+//' | cat -s > "$file" ; done
```

However, this had very unreliable results, with most files becoming completely empty and only a few files having the intended results. What's more, the files that did work seemed to change randomly every time I retried, as different files would get correctly edited in every run. What's going on?

Note: This is more of a theoretical question, because I realize I could use a workaround like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in * ; do 
    cat "$file" | sed 's/^ \+//' | cat -s > "$file"-tmp
    rm "$file"
    mv "$file"-tmp "$file"
done
```

But that seems unnecessarily convoluted. So why is the "direct" method so unreliable?

Comment: Repeat question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922449/how-can-i-replace-mutliple-empty-lines-with-a-single-empty-line-in-bash

Comment: @BroSlow My question isn't really a duplicate because it is less concerned with "how to do it", rather asking "why this particular way doesn't work".

Comment: Makes sense, just don't think that was clear from the original question.

Comment: @BroSlow You're right, the question title is misleading. I have changed the title to clarify the question.

Comment: BTW, there's no reason for the `rm`. You can `mv` a file over another file that already exists atomically, and that's the preferred approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unpredictability happens because there's a race condition between two stages in the pipeline, `cat "$file"` and `cat -s > "$file"`.

The first tries to open the file and read from it, while the other tries to empty the file.

- If it's emptied before it's read, you get an empty file.
- If it's read before it's emptied, you get some data (but the file is emptied shortly after and the result is truncated unless it's very short).

If you have GNU sed, you can simply do `sed -i 'expression' *`

Comment: Thanks alot! This is exactly what  was looking for. I didn't know the whole pipeline got run simultaneously. I thought it went in stages, so I was confused at the results I was getting.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read from a file if you are writing to it at the same time. The `>` redirection first clears the file, so there is nothing more to read.

You can use `sed -i -e '/^$/d'` to remove empty lines (if your sed supports `-i`), which creates the temporary file under the hood.